# I am getting an infinite fetch duration when adding a similar third left join

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, date

I am using MySQL on Windows 10.

The query below should result in three groups of data sets that are different only in the date range.  It works for any two date ranges but when I try to run all three time frames together, the fetch duration never ends; it does not produce results.  I waited over 15 minutes and still nothing.

```
#set variable startDate
set @startDate := "2023-02-08 00:00:01";    #enter start date here "year-month-day 00:00:01"

select cpe.sku,  
ifnull(sum(month6.qty_ordered),0) as "6 Month Quantity Sold", month6.store_id,
ifnull(sum(month3.qty_ordered),0) as "3 Month Quantity Sold",
ifnull(sum(month1.qty_ordered),0) as "1 Month Quantity Sold"

from catalog_product_entity as cpe

#limit the date range.
left join(select created_at, qty_ordered, product_id, store_id
    from sales_order_item
    where sales_order_item.created_at > @startDate 
    and sales_order_item.created_at < date_add(@startDate, interval 6 month)) as month6 on cpe.entity_id = month6.product_id  
left join(select created_at, qty_ordered, product_id
    from sales_order_item
    where sales_order_item.created_at > @startDate
    and sales_order_item.created_at < date_add(@startDate , interval 3 month)) as month3 on cpe.entity_id  = month3.product_id 
left join(select created_at, qty_ordered, product_id
    from sales_order_item
    where sales_order_item.created_at > @startDate
    and sales_order_item.created_at < date_add(@startDate , interval 1 month)) as month1 on cpe.entity_id = month1.product_id 


#filter everything that isn't a bundle and count by sku and group by store_id
group by cpe.sku, month6.store_id
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 0):

**Better formulation**

Do only 1 `SELECT`.  Have suitable conditions in each of the 3 computed columns.  It seems like the "00.00.01" after midnight is 'wrong', especially if `@startDate` is a `DATETIME`.

Your code does not include `store_id` for the 3-mo and 1-mo parts; this seems to be *wrong* when doing `GROUP BY ... store_id`.

Change the `>` as indicated here:

```
    created_at >= @startDate
AND created_at  < @startDate + INTERVAL 6 MONTH   -- (( or 3 or 1 ))
```

You possibly need `GROUP BY cpe.sku` or `GROUP BY cpe.eneity_id`.  If so, the following may or may not be what you need.  Study this:

```
SELECT  cpe.sku,
        soi.store_id,
        SUM( soi.qty_ordered          ) AS "6 Month Quantity Sold",
        SUM( IF( soi.created_at  < @startDate + INTERVAL 3 MONTH,
                 soi.qty_ordered, 0 ) ) AS "3 Month Quantity Sold",
        SUM( IF( soi.created_at  < @startDate + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,
                 soi.qty_ordered, 0 ) ) AS "1 Month Quantity Sold"
    FROM  sales_order_item AS soi
    JOIN  cpe  ON soi.product_id = cpe.entity_id
    WHERE soi.created_at >= @startDate
      AND soi.created_at  < @startDate + INTERVAL 6 MONTH
    GROUP BY cpe.sku, soi.store_id;
```

Note that the outer `WHERE` filters down to exactly what the 6-mo needs.  And the `>= @startDate` takes care of half of the test for 3-mo and 1-mo.

If you want it to run significantly even faster, consider building and maintaining a [*Summary Table*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) that contains subtotals for each day.  Then, summing up that table would have much less work to do.

(Note how my `>=` and `<` are carefully designed to work with `DATE` and `DATETIME` equally well.  Furthermore. `SET @startDate := "2023-02-08";` suffices.)

**As for the slow third `LEFT JOIN`**...

Each of those `JOINs` is being run separately.  Then they need to be put together.  If there are 100 rows in the 3rd derived table, that slows down the query by a factor of 100.  (Probably not that bad, but still bad.)

It is better to `SUM` things *before* combining them.  However, I decided to carry the 'simplification' even further by avoiding the subqueries.

**INDEXes**

```
cpe:  INDEX(entity_id,  sku)
soi:  INDEX(created_at, product_id,  store_id, qty_ordered)
```